# Query specifications on disjoint entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring Data. I know I can use JPA `Specification<T>` (where T is my entity) dynamically to construct where-predicates lambda-style, and that JHipster has a number of facilities to dynamically build where-predicates based on user input. I have successfully integrated such predicates in simple root-entity query (`select [something] from [RootEntity] item`).

Now I have the problem that my query must span over unrelated entities in join, and so has to the filter.

- As said, some entities do not have a mapped relationship, and must have none
- The query maps to a DTO
- The query must be pageable
- Some filters are fixed and injected by code
- User will provide filter input for most of the attributes of all the three entities
- The query is still unclear to me at this stagr

HQL query is structured like

```
select A.field as field, ... B.field as field, ... C.field as field
from FirstEntity A left outer join
     SecondEntity B on (A.something = B.something) left outer join
     ThirdEntity C on (C.something = ?.something)
where ????
```

I haven't *tried* anything yet, mostly because the signature choice will affect everything else.

I am stuck at designing the method.

**I want to ask how to properly use `Specification` when the query spans over unrelated entities.**

I don't know if Spring Data accepts something like

```
@Query("[my hql text as above, with aliases]")
Page<DTO> doTheQuery(Specification<FirstEntity> firstFilter, Specification<SecondEntity> secondFilter, Specification<ThirdEntity> thirdFilter, Pageable pageable);
```

In the example above, there are three different filters.

Or

```
@Query("[my hql text as above, with aliases]")
Page<DTO> doTheQuery(Specification<?> singleFilter, Pageable pageable);
```

In this example, calling code should **properly** use [as](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Selection.html#alias(java.lang.String)) to instruct Hibernate that predicates apply to distinct root entities (ones that I already aliased A,B,C).

Comment: You can use `Criteria Api` in this case or get entities using `Specification` and then create `DTO`s by code

Comment: There is a ticket for the problem https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-51 It marks as `Unresolved`